# How to access parameters that have a $ in the beginning in Flutter/Dart

Tags: dart

I generate an object with parameters.  It's a mix of custom ones that I create (no $) or the SDK that I have integrated generated a bunch with $:

```
{$campaign_id: 471764, $campaign_name: TPUSA, $channel: email, $first_match: false, $first_match_link: false, $guaranteed_match: true, $link_id: 504455, $link_name: TPUSA Demo, $reinstall: false, $suspicious: false, $token: tpusademo, creatorID: timfong888, referralID: tpusa-demo}
```

I am able to access the params without $ but get one with it:

```
socialdata.creator.value = globalReferralData.linkParams['creatorID'];
socialdata.campaign.value = globalReferralData.linkParams['$campaign_id'];
```

Is there something I need to do to access the values that have $ without an error (I get an error for $campaign_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either escape the `$` by putting `\` before the `$` like: `'\$campaign_id'`.

Or specify you want a raw string where every character should be read as they are written by putting an `r` before the string definition like: `r'$campaign_id'`

Comment: Ah, I was wondering about that!  Why would the SDK put the $ in there to begin with?  I thought maybe it had some meaning like @.

Comment: I don't know what SDK you are talking about. But I have no idea why the keys in your JSON map are prefixed with `$`. But `$variablename` does have a specific meaning in Dart where it means you want to put the value of evaluating `variablename.toString()` into your `String`. Since you want the actual string `"$variablename"`, we need the escaping.

Comment: super thanks!  can't accept the answer yet because it needs 7 more minutes....but will